# Catching custom python exceptions both inside a package and as a package user

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, custom-exceptions

I'm developing a multi-level package in python:

```
/mega_package
    __init__.py
    a.py
    /medium_package
        __init__.py
        /internal_package
            __init__.py
            exceptions.py
```

Inside the `exceptions.py` module I have a custom Exception:

```
class VeryBadException(Exception):
    pass
```

I import this Exception from the module `a.py` in the mega package in the following way:

```
from medium_package.internal_package import VeryBadException
```

And I can catch it when running a main script in the context of the mega package.

When I import the `mega_package` as a plugin to an external module, I must import this exception in the following way:

```
from mega_package.medium_package.internal_package import VeryBadException
```

My problem is that if the one of the modules in the `mega_package` raise the `VeryBadException` I can't catch it.

My code looks like that:

```
import mega_package
try:
    mega_package.a.do_bad_thing()
except VeryBadException:
    print 'Got it!!!'
except Exception,e:
    print type(e)
    print type(VeryBadException())
```

and the output is

```
<class 'medium_package.internal_package.exceptions.VeryBadExcpetion'>
<class 'mega_package.medium_package.internal_package.exceptions.VeryBadExcpetion'>
```

**How can I resolve this in an elegant way?**

Comment: Did you try using `from .medium_package.internal_package import VeryBadException` inside `a` (note extra dot at the beginning)?